# How can i revert translation word changed by translation csv when module is disable

Tags: magento2, locale-translation

Actually my issue is that,

I have a custom module and i have add translation csv and in that csv file i have changed Add to Cart text to Purchase.

But when i have disable this module so button text not change.

So can you have anyone idea about that how can i revert translation words after disabled the module.

Comment: Did you execute static content command.
your language csv would be merged in pub folder so for language refresh you should execute static content command.

Comment: But i need when i disable module from system config not from config php

Comment: As my thought,  magento do not check with system config for it.
You would find it in /pub/static/frontend/Magento/{{theme}}/en_US/i18n in your csv file.

Comment: Yes you are right in that way this will work, but i have fine solution like this

Answer (score 0):

magento merge your csv file in `/pub/static/frontend/Magento/{{theme}}/{{store_lang}}/i18n/{{en_US}}.csv` folder. so it would not effect by disable module from admin side.

you need to execute `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f` command.

Comment: Yes you are right but this is not my requirement, that thing i have already knows. Thanks